# How to draw a conclusion from mixin PUG?

Tags: pug

I have a mixin of one commodity, does it have several other myxins? which contain arrays, and as a result I was faced with the problem of entering data in the course of calling my maksin

This is one of the arrays that you need to fill:

```
+size-list(item.sized).--square.--product-item
```

```html
mixin product-item(notice, name, price, size, old, oldprice, img, ...items)
+b.product-item
    +e.wrapper
        +e.compare
            +e.add.--compare(href="javascript:void(0);" title="")
                include ui-kit/icon.pug
                +icon("compare").--product-item
        +e.favorites
            +e.add.--favorites(href="javascript:void(0);" title="")
                include ui-kit/icon.pug
                +icon("favorites").--product-item
        if notice == 'vip'
            include ui-kit/label.pug
            +label('vip').--vip
        else if notice == 'hit'
            include ui-kit/label.pug
            +label('хит').--hit
        else if notice == 'new'
            include ui-kit/label.pug
            +label('new').--new
        else if notice == 'sale'
            include ui-kit/label.pug
            +label('%').--sale
        +b.button.--product-quck.js-qick-view(href="javascript:void(0);" title=name) быстрый просмотр
        +e.image-wrapper
            +e.image.js-wrapper-image(src=img, alt=name, title=name)
        +e.color
            include select-color.pug
            +select-color(...items).--product-item
        +e.info
            +e.name #{name}
            +e.size #{size}
            +e.hidden-info
                +e.size-change
                    include ui-kit/hr.pug
                    +hr().--product-item
                    include ui-kit/size-list.pug
                    
                    +size-list(item.sized).--square.--product-item
                               include characteristic-info.pug
                +characteristic-info({'items': [{
                        'title': 'Ш х В х Г',
                        'definition': '40 x 55 x 20/24 см'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': 'Объем',
                        'definition': '38/43 л'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': 'Масса',
                        'definition': '2,5 кг'
                    }
                ]}).--product-item
            include ui-kit/price.pug
            +price(price, old, oldprice, ".-").--product-item
```

The conclusion itself tried to do so, but swears on the bracket:

```html
+product-item("vip", "American Tourister Sunset Square Spinner 13G*908", "22 100", "Огромный чемодан-спиннер (XL)", "", "oldprice", "images/content/announcement-1.jpg", "", "#f3e222", "transparent", "#926ca7", "#926ca7", "#7fd0af", "#0bb8b2",{ 'items': [{
                        'size': [{
                            "textLabel": "XL",
                            "name": "size-105",
                            "id": "size-type-120",
                            "checked": true
                        }, {
                            "textLabel": "L",
                            "name": "size-105",
                            "id": "size-type-121"
                        }, {
                            "textLabel": "M",
                            "name": "size-105",
                            "id": "size-type-122"
                        }, {
                            "textLabel": "S",
                            "name": "size-105",
                            "id": "size-type-123"
                        }]
                    ]}
                })
```

What other options do I have? What did I do wrong? Or can it somehow be possible to design mixin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was decided so

```html
mixin product-item(notice, name, price, size, old, oldprice, img, sized, info,...items)
    +b.product-item
        +e.wrapper
            +e.compare
                +e.add.--compare(href="javascript:void(0);" title="")
                    include ui-kit/icon.pug
                    +icon("compare").--product-item
            +e.favorites
                +e.add.--favorites(href="javascript:void(0);" title="")
                    include ui-kit/icon.pug
                    +icon("favorites").--product-item
            if notice == 'vip'
                include ui-kit/label.pug
                +label('vip').--vip
            else if notice == 'hit'
                include ui-kit/label.pug
                +label('хит').--hit
            else if notice == 'new'
                include ui-kit/label.pug
                +label('new').--new
            else if notice == 'sale'
                include ui-kit/label.pug
                +label('%').--sale
            +b.button.--product-quck.js-qick-view(href="javascript:void(0);" title=name) быстрый просмотр
            +e.image-wrapper
                +e.image.js-wrapper-image(src=img, alt=name, title=name)
            
            +e.info
                +e.info-text
                    include select-color.pug
                    +select-color(...items).--product-item
                    +e.name #{name}
                    +e.size #{size}
                +e.hidden-info
                    +e.size-change
                        include ui-kit/hr.pug
                        +hr().--product-item
                        include ui-kit/size-list.pug
                        +size-list(sized).--square.--product-item
                    include characteristic-info.pug
                    +characteristic-info(info).--product-item
                include ui-kit/price.pug
                +price(price, old, oldprice, ".-").--product-item
```

And the conclusion:

```html
+product-item("new", "American Tourister Sunset Square Spinner 13G*908", "22 100", "Огромный чемодан-спиннер (XL)", true, "24 500", "images/content/announcement-1.jpg",
                    [{
                        "textLabel": "XL",
                        "name": "size-100",
                        "id": "size-type-227",
                        "checked": true
                    }, {
                        "textLabel": "L",
                        "name": "size-100",
                        "id": "size-type-228"
                    }, {
                        "textLabel": "M",
                        "name": "size-100",
                        "id": "size-type-229"
                    }, {
                        "textLabel": "S",
                        "name": "size-100",
                        "id": "size-type-230"
                    }],
                    [{
                        'title': 'Ш х В х Г',
                        'definition': '40 x 55 x 20/24 см'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': 'Объем',
                        'definition': '38/43 л'
                    },
                    {
                        'title': 'Масса',
                        'definition': '2,5 кг'
                    }], "", "#f3e222", "transparent", "#926ca7", "#926ca7", "#7fd0af", "#0bb8b2")
```